# Checking for common interactors within a time range in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset which can be recreated using the following code:

```
   import pandas as pd
    
    data3 =  [[20210308, 'A','B',100], 
              [20210307, 'B','A',95],
            [20210307, 'B','A',65],
            [20210305, 'A','C',50],
            [20210304, 'D','E',25],
            [20210303, 'E','D',200],
            [20210201,'E','B',10 ], 
            [20210101, 'X','X',50]] 
    
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns = ['Date_1', 'Interactor_A','Interactor_B','Value']) 
    
    df3['Date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date_1'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

The final dataset looks like this, I made the last column for date time in case some date time functions were required for the solution:

```
     Date_1 Interactor_A Interactor_B  Value     Date_2
0  20210308            A            B    100 2021-03-08
1  20210307            B            A     95 2021-03-07
2  20210307            B            A     65 2021-03-07
3  20210305            A            C     50 2021-03-05
4  20210304            D            E     25 2021-03-04
5  20210303            E            D    200 2021-03-03
6  20210201            E            B     10 2021-02-01
7  20210101            X            X     50 2021-01-01
```

What I'm trying to do is detect if two people interact with each other within a 3 day period and the value of their interaction is within a 90% to 110% range. That is does A interact with B as Interactor_A and does B interact back with A as Interactor_A and their interaction happens within a 3 day time window and is the value of their interactions within a 90% to 110% range?

By this logic, only the first two rows would be selected as A interacts with B and then B interacts back with A and the value of their interaction is within a 90% to 110% band because 95/100 or 100/95 is within a 90% to 110% band. Similarly the D-E and E-D interaction won't be selected because 25/200 and 200/25 are both outside of a 90% to 110% band. The B-A interaction in Index 2 also won't be selected because it's not in the 90% to 110% band even though it's in the 3 day window.

I'm trying a bunch of solutions via SQL:

1. I tried an inner join on the table to itself but that just gave me results similar to the last row where X interacted with X
2. I tried a self join that aggregated over a 3 day window but that only aggregates A's values over a 3 day period in total, doesn't capture any interactions.

Is there a way in Python that can only return the first two rows (A-B and B-A in Index 0 and 1) because they satisfy the condition of interacting with each other within a 3 day time window and the value of their interaction is within a 90% to 110% band?

Comment: @ScottBoston So ideally my result would just select the 2 rows of A-B and B-A interaction that you see in the first Index 0,1 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the DataFrame with itself, using `['Interactor_A', 'Interactor_B']` as left keys and `['Interactor_B', 'Interactor_A']` as right keys, which gives us a DataFrame with pairs of interactions like `A-B` and `B-A` in each row, on which we can calculate the number of days between such interactions (the `days_diff` column), and the ratio of values (the `value_ratio` column). Then we can filter based on the values of `days_diff` and `value_ratio`.

As the last step, we only take the 'left' side of the merge, and `drop_duplicates` (because `merge` will generate all possible combinations, and some of their 'left' sides may be the same):

```
# create a copy of df3
z = df3.copy()

# keep interactions within 3 days, value ratio between 0.9 and 1.1,
# and Interactor_A != Interactor_B
z = z.merge(z,
            left_on=['Interactor_A', 'Interactor_B'],
            right_on=['Interactor_B', 'Interactor_A'],
            suffixes=['', '_'])
z['days_diff'] = (z['Date_2'] - z['Date_2_']).abs().dt.days
z['value_ratio'] = z['Value'] / z['Value_']
z = z.loc[z['days_diff'].le(3) &
          z['value_ratio'].between(0.9, 1.1) &
          z['Interactor_A'].ne(z['Interactor_B'])]

# use columns from df3 and drop duplicates
z = z[df3.columns].drop_duplicates()

z
```

Output:

```
     Date_1 Interactor_A Interactor_B  Value     Date_2
0  20210308            A            B    100 2021-03-08
1  20210307            B            A     95 2021-03-07
```

Comment: Hi Perl, some feedback on this:
> The question lays out that it's not the absolute value of the interaction that needs to be between 90 and 110 but the percentage band. So it's specifying that the value of the interaction between A_B and B_A needs to be close to each other. Thus, if A interacted with B with a value of 60 on 01_Jan_2021 and B interacted back with A with a value of 65 on 02_Jan_2021, this should still qualify them for selection.

Comment: @Malik Right, sorry I missed that somehow. It's an easy fix though, let me update the answer...

Comment: @Malik Updated, please have a look. One thing to note is that the value ratio is not symmetric (so, for example if values are 90 and 100, we get 0.9, which passes the filter, but if we take 100 an 90, we get 1.11, which does not pass the filter). One option to 'fix' this is to use the symmetric midpoint formula `2 * (x - y) / (x + y)` and filter based on that

Comment: I've also added the condition that `Interactor_A != Interactor_B`, otherwise we would also get the X-X row, which as I understand we don't want to be included

Comment: I tried out the new solution including the recommended formula and they meet all the conditions, I have accepted the answer. Thanks!